# Get an image from an article/entity

Tags: entities, 8, media

How do I easiest get an image (its path) from the article content type included in Drupal 8?

What I have is an entity. Using `$image = $node->fields['field_image']` gives me a hell of a structure, though.

Is there no easier way to get the image path? Also I cannot find the URL in this, what I get is some sort of target_id (the file ID?).

Comment: What does `get_class ($node->fields['field_image'])` give you?

Comment: Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileFieldItemList is what it gives me, this only seem to contain properties of what is allowed to upload.

Comment: If you iterate the list what types are its members? I haven't checked, but I'd hope for some reasonably strong typing of the field. If all else fails you can use `file_load()` and one of the methods available on [`Drupal\file\FileInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21FileInterface.php/interface/FileInterface/8)

Comment: Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem is what I get, not sure how to properly handling that, though.

Comment: file_load is a last resort, but it's depricated and feels so wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Didn't see this before.

The shortest way to get the referenced entity for a single-value field is this:

```
$node->field_image->entity->url()
```

You can also specify the delta explicitly:

```
$node->field_image[0]->entity->url()
```

This works with a lot of ArrayAccess and __get() magic.

See also the great cheat sheet at http://wizzlern.nl/drupal/drupal-8-entity-cheat-sheet. and https://www.drupal.org/node/1795854 and the other documentation pages there for more information (still very much work in progress).

Comment: Nice! I was wondering how we can get the image alt. I tried $node->field_image[0]->entity->alt and $node->field_image[0]->entity->image->alt; which I found in the documentation you mentioned but it does not work with the node entity I think.

Comment: the alt/title is not on the referenced file entity but the field item itself. Just $node->field_image[0]->alt should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

What ended up working for me in D8 is:

```
$imageUrl = $node->get('field_image')->entity->uri->value;
```

Using `kint($node->get('field_image')->entity)` and looking through the array was very helpful

[image]

Then in my twig file I used:

```
<img class="top-article-image" src="{{ file_url(imageUrl) }}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

So my solution was to use the method "referencedEntities()" found in the nodeobject. This gave me an array of File-objects which I could iterate through and use the method "url()" from the file objects to retrieve a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

If your node has more than one image you can use this to get a array of the image urls (helpful for making slideshow modules among alot of other useful things)

```
$allImagesFound = false;
$imageUrls = array();
$numberOfImages = 0;
while(!$allImagesFound)
{
    //make sure we are not calling a null value, if so then we have found all images
    if($node->get('your_image_field_name')[$numberOfImages] != null) {
        $imageUrls[] = $node->get('your_image_field_name')[$numberOfImages]->entity->url();
        $numberOfImages++;
    } else {
        $allImagesFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

The imageUrls array will hold all the urls for any images associated with the nodes field.
Hope this helps.